# Date Trigger Filter List Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a formarray and a list of items that once I change the date it will trigger it to the date form and change the list depending on the date how to achieve that.

> HTML

```
<td>
  <input matInput type="date" 
  formControlName="asOfDate" 
  class="form-control"  
  (ngModelChange)="onValueChange($event)">
</td>
```

> .TS

```
asOfDate: any = new Date().toISOString().substring(0,10); 
ngOninit(){
this.fg = this.fb.group({
name:[],
array:this.fb.array([this.createGroup])
})
}

createGroup():FormGroup{
return this.fb.group({
asOfdate:[],
listItem:[]
}))

onValueChange(value: Date): void {
    this.asOfDate = value;
    console.log(this.asOfDate)
  }

getList(){
      this.services.LookUpList(5,1, this.asOfDate).subscribe((response: myDTO) => {
      this.Object = response;
      this.myDTO= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.Object.items))
      console.log(response)
      })
    }
```

> SERVICES

```
LookUpList(size:number, index:number, asOfDate:number){
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.append('Size', String(size));
    params = params.append('Index', String(index));
    params = params.append('asOfDate', String(asOfDate));
    const res = this.http.get(this.appsetting.baseURL + 'MyList/listforcreation', {params});
    return res;
  }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing? Do you have an error of any kind?

Comment: @FabianStrathaus when i tried to change the date it wont like search it or filter the list

Answer (score 3):

**Update** use startWith operator to the fisrt time

Two things before answer:

1. Please, don't copy code if you don't know what the code make (the
   use of `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.Object.items))` do
   **nothing** in your code (it's used only to make a "deep copy" of an object).
2. Your function getList it's not called any time you change the
   "input", so it's not possible you refrehs "nothing" when change.

Well, when we can refresh a list based in the change of a FormControl, usually we create an observable based in valueChange and, using switchMap operator to return the observable we want

```
this.observable$=this.formControl.valueChanges(pipe(
   //we can add startWith operator
  startWith(this.formControl.value),
   //we are not interesting in the value else
  switchMap((value:any)=>{
    return this.services.LookUpList(5,1, value)
  })
))
```

We can subscribe to the observable and use a variable or use async pipe in .html

```
<input [formControl]="formControl">
<div *ngFor="let item of observable$|async">
   {{item.prop1}}
</div>
```

If we has a FormArray, we has severals FormControls, so we need severals "observables" (Your question is not clear for me to be sure if you're mannaging a formControl or a FormArray). So we are going to

```
observables$=Observables<any>[]=[]  //declare an array of observables

/*Imagine you has a 
  form=new FormGroup({
     array:new FormArray([])
  })
*/

//a getter of the formArray
get array()
{
    return this.form.get('array') as FormArray
}

//create a function that not only return a FormGroup else 
//give value to an element of the observables
createGroup(data:any=null)
{
   data=data || {asOfDate:null,..others by defect values}
   const index=this.form.get('array').length;
   const group=new FormGroup({
      asOfDate:new FormControl(data.asOfDate)
      ...others controls..
   })
```

```
   observables$[index]=group.valueChanges(pipe(
```

```
   observables$[index]=group.get('asOfDate').valueChanges(pipe(
      startWith(data.asOfDate),
      switchMap((value:any)=>{
        return this.services.LookUpList(5,1, value)
      })
   ))
   return group
}
```

now we can use the array of Observables

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
   <div formArrayName="array">
       <div *ngFor="let group of array.controls;let i=index" 
            [formGroupName]="i">
            <input formControlName="asOfDate">
            <div *ngFor="let item of observable$[i]|async">
               {{item.prop1}}
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Update** using FormBuilder, the createGroup function becomes like

```
createGroup(data:any=null)
{
   data=data || {asOfDate:null,..others by defect values}
   const index=this.form.get('array').length;
   const group=this.fb.group({
      asOfDate:data.asOfDate,
      ...others controls..
   })
   //sorry, we listen the control valueChanges, not the group
   observables$[index]=group.get('asOfDate').valueChanges(pipe(
      startWith(data.asOfDate),
      switchMap((value:any)=>{
        return this.services.LookUpList(5,1, value)
      })
   ))
   return group
}
```

Comment: i got an error when i tried to use your code the observable and the valuechanges,

that's not how i formarray

this.fg = this.fb.group({
name:[],
})

Comment: @Ruth should be: `array:this.fb.array([this.createGroup()])` -see the two parenthesis, you're calling a function-. You need make in three steps:`const group=this.fb.group(..); this.observables$[i]=...;return group;`. But has no much sense the "listItem" belong to the FormArray if you needn't change the values.

Comment: the value changes still got an error
 CreateList(i:any=null)
  {
  this.fg.valueChanges.subscribe((data: Observable<any>) => {
    startWith(data),
    switchMap((value:any) => {
      return this.services.LookUpList(5,1,value)
    })
   })
i tried this but it wont work too

Comment: @Ruth sorry, It's **not** this.fg.valueChanges else this.fb.get('asOfDate').valueChanges. And in subscribe, "data" is `any` (really is `string|any`) **not** `Observable<any>` -is the value of the input- (just corrected in answer)